# Square Connect: Delete active tokens?

Tags: square-connect

I am working with a few beta sites to prepare my application for approval by Square for their marketplace.  I am limited to 10 test accounts.  I need to remove some existing accounts and add new ones - no need to go over 10, but my current limit on "Active Tokens" has been hit.

Is there a way to delete an active merchant token, reducing my active token limit, so that I can create a new account?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete active access tokens with the [Revoke Token](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#post-revoke) endpoint.

Note that if a merchant has more than one access token for your application, this endpoint revokes all of them, regardless of which token you specify.

Comment: Thanks!  I was looking for this in the docs and now I found it.  The Oauth section seems like it's in sort of a strange place.  Appreciate your calling it out.